# RegExp question mark does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

```
/(?:vk\.com\/|\[)?(?<domain>[\w\-.]+)/
```

---

Why does this regular expression not work correctly? It should match the string "myacc", but it matches "https"

```
https://vk.com/myacc
myacc
[myacc|aabbccdd]
```

Comment: `?` works correctly, your expections seem wrong. Remove `?`, use `(?:vk\.com\/|\[)(?<domain>[\w\-.]+)`